# Group strings in a list using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, grouping

I am trying to use regex to group items based on similarity, so instead of having a lot of items, I can group them to have much fewer. But it doesn't work as expected and it gives wrong output. below are expected output and my current output.

mini example: `'k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4'` -> `'k(1|2|3|4)'`

Actual code:

```
import re

loc_list = [
    'phone100-500-cas-ras9-f51-s10-k2',
    'phone100-500-cas-ras9-f52-s10-k2',
    'phone100-500-cas-ras9-f50-s10-k2',
    'phone100-500-cas-ras9-f50-s9-k3',
    'phone100-500-cas-ras9-f50-s9-k1',
    'Telephone100-500-cas-ras9-f50-s9-k2']

split_loc_list = [phone.split("-") for phone in loc_list]

locs = {}

for loc in split_loc_list:
    locs.setdefault("-".join(loc[0:4]), {}).\
                        setdefault("f", set()).add(loc[4].strip("f"))
    locs.setdefault("-".join(loc[0:4]), {}).\
                        setdefault("s", set()).add(loc[5].strip("s"))
    locs.setdefault("-".join(loc[0:4]), {}).\
                        setdefault("k", set()).add(loc[6].strip("k"))
prove = []
for loc, vals in locs.items():
    f_vals_sorted = sorted(list(map(int, vals["f"])))
    f_vals_joined = "|".join(map(str, f_vals_sorted))
    if "|" in f_vals_joined:
        f_vals_joined = f"({f_vals_joined})"
    s_vals_sorted = sorted(list(map(int, vals["s"])))
    s_vals_joined = "|".join(map(str, s_vals_sorted))
    if "|" in s_vals_joined:
        s_vals_joined = f"({s_vals_joined})"
    k_vals_sorted = sorted(list(map(int, vals["k"])))
    k_vals_joined = "|".join(map(str, k_vals_sorted))
    if "|" in k_vals_joined:
        k_vals_joined = f"({k_vals_joined})"
    prove.append(f"{loc}-f{f_vals_joined}-s{s_vals_joined}-k{k_vals_joined}")
print("|".join(prove))
```

Current output which is wrong:

```
phone100-500-cas-ras9-f(50|51|52)-s(9|10)-k(1|2|3)|Telephone100-500-cas-ras9-f50-s9-k2
```

Expected output:

```
Telephone100-500-cas-ras9-f50-s9-k2|phone100-500-cas-ras9-f50-s9-k(1|3)|phone100-500-cas-ras9-f(50|51|52)-s10-k2
```

Comment: thanks, I have edited the post

Comment: Great, that clarified a lot. I edited it too to make it even clearer. Hope it helps. LMK if I did anything wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't `...f50-s10-k2|...f(51|52)-s10-k2` be `...f(50|51|52)-s10-k2`?

Comment: Thanks,  Yes, I have updated it

Comment: Are you trying to build a kind of a regex trie?

Comment: FWIW I was able to simplify the code with some loops and a defaultdict: [gist](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/0d9afbbcd2956adeb060ae97a5150635)

Comment: Can you share it please?

Comment: @thesmall Yeah I linked it in my comment above, but the link is kinda small, sorry. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/0d9afbbcd2956adeb060ae97a5150635